# Compute the Laurent Expansion

Tags: laurent-series

I'm struggling on how to compute laurent expansion, for example in the following question:

$$
f(z)= \frac {1}{z(z-1)(z-2)}
$$

in the Annulus $(0;0,1)$ i.e. the disc centred at 0 of radius 1 and punctured at 0.

A walkthrough of the solution to this problem would be greatly appreciated so I can apply it in future problems.

Thanks!

Comment: I am guessing that around $\;z=0\;$ ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have here that

$$|z|<1\;,\;\;\left|\frac z2\right|<1\;,\;\;\text{so first partial fractions:}$$

$$\frac1{z(z-1)(z-2)}=\frac1{2z}-\frac1{z-1}+\frac1{2(z-2)}=\frac1{2z}+\frac1{1-z}-\frac1{4\left(1-\frac z2\right)}=$$

$$=\frac1{2z}+\frac12\left(1+z+z^2+\ldots\right)-\frac14\left(1+\frac z2+\frac{z^2}4+\ldots\right)=$$

$$\frac1{2z}-\frac12+\frac38z+\frac7{16}z^2+\ldots$$

Can you come up with the general expression...?

Comment: Should the second expansion have a $\frac {1}{4}$ outside the bracket? So the next step is to try to think of how to express the last line as a series?

Comment: @juper Good catch. Typo corrected, thanks.

Comment: so it's the expression: $\frac {1}{2z} + \frac {1}{2} \sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n - \frac {1}{4} \sum_{n=0}^\infty (\frac {z}{2})^n$ ?

Comment: @juper Well, yes...obviously. I meant a closed, simpler expression, perhaps even with one single sum...

Comment: can i just combine the series into one? I'm not really sure

Comment: @juper Yes, you can combine the two series in one, and it isn't that hard. By the way, checking all your questions I see you don't use to upvote and/or  accept many of hte answers you get...

Comment: yes sorry, I usually say thanks and forget to upvote. I assume I can just substract the two sums into one? I have gone to my previous questions and selected the correct answer now.

Comment: @juper Exactly that: observe that there's a very simple formula for the substraction of terms with equal power of $\;x\;$ ...

Comment: yes as i thought. Thank you for your time and help on this question. It's been very useful!